# Simular click ao abrir a página

Tags: javascript

Existe forma, de quando alguém entra em um site web, um evento JavaScript "simular" um `click`? Ou seja o JavaScript fazer um `click` no site automaticamente mal a pessoa entra.

No caso eu tenho um anuncio de publicidade que só abre quando alguém clica na página. Ou seja é necessário clicar na página para abrir uma nova página de publicidade.

```
<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.liveadexchanger.com/a/display.php?r=961387"></script>
```

No caso existiria forma, de mal algum usuário entra, abrir essa página simulando um "click". Pois eu já tentei todas as formas que me disseram e não consegui.

Comment: `document.getElementById("meuElemento").click()`

Comment: No lugar de meu elemento, coloco o que? Um div por exemplo?

Comment: Tentei aplicar, mas não consegui.

Comment: Respondi com mais detalhes pra você.

Comment: Seria ao clicar em qualquer parte da página disparar um outro evento click?

Comment: Não, no caso só de ver já abriria aquele javascript simulando um evento.

Comment: @Gonçalo por acaso o que você quer não é obter controle do cursor do mouse do usuário, que iria até certa parte da página e  clicaria sozinho num elemento (uma div por exemplo)?. Porque se for isso acho que não dá, seria uma falha de segurança...

Answer (score 3):

Basta chamar o [`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) num elemento. Exemplo:

```
document.getElementById("meuElemento").click();
```

Onde `meuElemento` é o `id` de um elemento qualquer no html, contanto que o mesmo possua evento `click`, como por exemplo elementos `input`, `button`, `a`, `div` etc.

Para ele ser chamado no carregamento da página deve estar dentro do evento [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load):

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById("meuElemento").click();
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/uL3beo0d/), [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/uL3beo0d/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: Não consegui fazer aquilo que eu queria, mas editei a minha resposta para dar mais detalhes.

Comment: @Gonçalo editou a resposta ou a pergunta?

Comment: A pergunta peço desculpa.

Answer (score 2):

Faça o seguinte:

No Javascript:

```
function teste(){
   alert("Teste")
}
window.onload = function() {
   document.getElementById("elementoTeste").click();
}
```

No html:

```
<input type="button" onclick="teste()" id="elementoTeste">
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer aquilo que eu queria, mas editei a minha resposta para dar mais detalhes.

Comment: A pergunta peço desculpa

Comment: @DeeSouza deveria funcionar com o exemplo que passei. Você consegue incluir o teu fonte na pergunta também? Verifique se o id do elemento está certo

Comment: @renan deixa pra lá, tanto faz pra mim o que os outros postam nas respostas deles.

Comment: @DeeSouza vai responder a pergunta ou vai ficar só causando? Ajudando a transformar isso aqui ainda mais num fórum ou num yahoo respostas, mais do que já é ? Tá cheio de [artigo por aí](http://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/) contra uso de evento inline html, só pesquisar...

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown que que eu fiz ? Estou aqui na boa. Pessoal já respondeu.

Comment: @DeeSouza de boa djow.

Comment: Último caso uso `trigger()`.

Comment: @DeeSouza boa, só que `trigger()` é jQuery.

Comment: Sim, por isso disse em último caso.

Answer (score 0):

Para mim consegui fazer funcionar dessa maneira. Implementei o click automático em 5000 mls e depois encerrei o loop após 1000 mls. Ficando assim, somente 1 click automático.

```
<script> var myVar = setInterval(function ({document.getElementById("teste").click();}, 500); setInterval(function () {clearInterval(myVar)}, 1000); </script>
```